# How to change layout name programmatically?

Tags: android, layout

Can you change layout name with code?

I have one activity and couple of buttons. every button send extra string and activity checks what is extra and it updates the textview text, but can you change layout name?

I mean the string in strings.xml for name of layout.

so let me explain

I have four buttons
each button starts one activity but puts other extra string with intent.putExtra
so one button will change textviews text to something and other to something else(i'm checking for extra string and thats how im changing string)
now i want to change the activity name shown in app itself to correspond buttons name

SOLVED ! with this.setTitle

Comment: What do you mean by a layout name?

Comment: Why do you want to change the layout name?  And what does it mean?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an example?  Like, maybe you could show your layout XML and point out exactly which part you would like to adjust from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can not rename your layout file explicitly from the code. Its out of the android application structure and scope.

Layouts are the part of your project structure. You can change the views of your layout dynamically even change the layout. But you can not modify or rename the file of your layout. As its part of your project and out of scope.

**EDITED:**

You can change the title of your activity at runtime using

```
 setTitle("Activity Name");
```

> Change the title associated with this activity. If this is a top-level activity, the title for its window will change. If it is an embedded activity, the parent can do whatever it wants with it.

Comment: i dont want to change name of layout file i mean the name that shows up on application

Comment: You want to change the application name at the run time ? @Brsgamer

Comment: no no no i want to change name of single activity not application

Comment: The one way you can define the activity name runtime using the `setTitle("Activity Name");` Which you will have to call before the `setContentView` method.

Comment: Yes. You can pass the string from one activity to another as per your needs and set the title.